# Stop my photos from getting onto Facebook?

Tags: facebook, google-plus, facebook-photos, facebook-privacy

How can I stop photos of me from getting onto Facebook or Google Plus? I am not a user of social networks and do not want my photo on these networks. I am very concerned I may be added by friends or family and tagged. Is there any way a non-user can find out if their photos are on any of these sites other than a legal warrant?

Comment: If you're not a user of the service, you can't be "tagged". That's not to say that your name couldn't be used in the image caption/description.

Answer (score 2):

There are about [250 *billion* photos on Facebook](http://www.theverge.com/2013/9/17/4741332/facebook-users-have-uploaded-a-quarter-trillion-photos-since-launch) at the moment. How could you possibly find if you are in any of them if you are not a user (i.e. you can’t see them)? The only possible way (and by possible I mean *moon shot*) would be to run these photos through some kind of image-recognition algorithm, that should be provided by Facebook itself — not available to the public, to my knowledge.

The only way, in my opinion at least, would be for you to create an account and use it to reject any attempt to get tagged. But this, of course, requires for you to become friends with the people that could potentially tag you.